# xcode 7.2 couldn’t communicate with a helper application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7.1

When i create an xcode project getting following error, this error appears every time when i create a new project can any one help me to figure out the reason

[image: Screenshot added]

Comment: what is your mac os version?

Comment: Have u checked with this http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-fix-couldnt-communicate-with-a-helper-application-in-xcode-7/

Answer (score 4):

Try to execute the following:

```
xcrun git config --global user.email you@domain.com
xcrun git config --global user.name "your name here"
```

It worked for me couple times already (with older MacOS/Xcode versions as well)

Comment: fixed my "Xcode couldn't communicate with a helper application" message when attempting to use git in Xcode 8.3.3