# How can I commit code without "Couldn't communicate with a helper application" message

Tags: xcode, git

How can I commit a large number of files (4446) without having an error message in xCode 8 (Version 8.2.1 (8C1002))

See below:

[image]

The solution exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282427/xcode-7-2-couldn-t-communicate-with-a-helper-application)  do not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

One of the solution to this (and it is a workaround at this point) is to commit smaller number of files at once (few hundreds). That still takes a lot of time to do it manually because you need to click each of the files one by one.

The better option is to use the command line and completely bypass Xcode (exit the application). I ran the command from my Xcode repository directory as follow:

1. git add -A
2. git commit -m "Your commit message"
3. git push origin master

After the "git push" command I launched Xcode again and made sure that the version control was up to date.

Note: I still believe there is a bug in Xcode 8.x around Git and Source Control with a big amount of files.