# Xcode 8 source control broken

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I came across strange issue with source control (git) on Xcode 8.

While removing some old, already merged to master branches the popup appeared stating `Couldn’t communicate with a helper application`.

The branches were removed but another issue came up, so when commiting I have something like this:

`Repository View` seem to be ok:

[image]

`Project View` should look somewhat the same but is kinda weird:

[image]

I can commit but when trying to remove a branch the warning popup still appears.
I've searched for solution, found this one:
[xcode 7.2 couldn’t communicate with a helper application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282427/xcode-7-2-couldn-t-communicate-with-a-helper-application)
but when I check in Terminal with `xcrun git config --global user.email` and `xcrun git config --global user.name` it gives me the proper values.

I use SourceTree as well and it works flawlessly without any warnings.

All other projects are ok - no warnings and no weird `Project View`.

**Update:**

All other projects have normal `Project View` but apparently the warning popup `Couldn’t communicate with a helper application` appears when I try to remove a branch.

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Xcode 9 and updating project solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The working solution for this issue is to do a manual commit:

The solution is to add changes with a git command. Change to your working directory (that contains a /.git folder) and execute:

```
git commit -a -m "Commit title here"
```

Original post: [Xcode 9 commit: Couldn't communicate with helper application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607843/xcode-9-commit-couldnt-communicate-with-helper-application/46947162#46947162)